# How would I print these lists?

Tags: python, arrays, variables, loops

```
number = [1, 2, 3, 4]
letter = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

for s in number:         
    print s

for d in letter:
    print d
```

I want the loop to print out

```
1
a
2
b
```

etc, this loop was the closest ive gotten

Comment: What if the array have a different size?

Comment: Thanks everyone, never knew about the zip function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [zip()](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> for n, l in zip(number, letter):
...     print n
...     print l
...     
... 
1
a
2
b
3
c
4
d
```

`zip()` will create a list of tuples from the lists `number` and `letter`. Each tuple is the element at the position `i` from both lists, `(number[i], letter[i])`

The zipped list looks like this:

```
>>> zip(number, letter)
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [zip](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> number = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> letter = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> for a in zip(number,letter):
...     print a[0]
...     print a[1]
```

Comment: Why only in the console? It can as well be used regularly in a program.

Comment: Like the one you selected was ran in the console. Because it is easy for me to try in the console. You can use it in a program if you want.

Comment: The one *I* selected? :-)

Comment: Yes, sorry :D. But yes, it is basically the same. The question was crying out "use zip, use zip"! :) I should not point out the obvious about using the console in the aswer, can be misunderstood. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
print "\n".join(str(j) for i in zip(number, letter) for j in i)
```

[`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip) combines the two lists into a list of tuples. Then the iteration is carried out over each element `j` of each tuple `i`. [`join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) concatenates all the elements to a single string, separated by a newline `"\n"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print consecutive numbers for those letters, you can use:

```
for i, ch in enumerate(letter, start=1):
    print i
    print ch
```

Comment: What if the numbers don't match the `index` given by `enumerate()`?

Comment: @msvalkon Very easy: then one of the other answers should be chosen.